# Using Regular Expression in Find (CentOS 6.7)

Tags: regex, centos, find

How can I use the regular expression `\w{7}[D]\w{6}$` in a find command?

Comment: To find a command, such as...??

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you looked at the man page for `find`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
find -regextype posix-extended -regex 'YOUR REGEX'
```

`-regextype` options are:

```
findutils-default, awk, egrep, emacs, gnu-awk, grep, posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep, posix-extended
```

---

**References:**

[Find Utils Manual (CentOS)](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/16467287/numer/1/nazwa/find)

Comment: Thank you!  I just missing/nit understanding the posix-extended piece.  Here's what worked for me. 

`find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\w{7}[D]\w{6}$'`